# Remove &#10; char from imap mail extract

Tags: php, html, gmail, imap

I am trying to fetch a mail in imap from Google, I'm using the `imap()` function from PHP IMAP library and I want to use a `preg_match()` call on my mail content but I have a strange issue, I have curious break lines altering the normal `preg_match()`.

More details:
I have in my markup something like that:

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING=5 RULES=GROUPS FRAME=BOX>

<THEAD>
<TR> <TH>Résumé points de classement</TH>       <TH>Extérieur</TH>            <TH>Domicile</TH> </TR>
</THEAD>

<TBODY>
<TR> <TD>Équipe</TD>                      <TD>Milan</TD>         <TD>Arsenal</TD> </TR>

<TR> <TD>Performance du match</TD>         <TD>0</TD>  <TD>19</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Étoiles équipe</TD>         <TD>0</TD>   <TD>0</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Points totaux</TD>              <TD>3195</TD>       <TD>3273</TD> </TR>

<TR> <TD>Niveau actuel</TD>       <TD>22</TD>   <TD>22</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Points pour le prochain niveau</TD> <TD>5</TD>    <TD>127</TD> </TR>
</TBODY>

</TABLE>
```

I am running this code to extract the body for example:

```
<?php
// $message is the previous markup.
$str = substr($message, 321, 10);
var_dump($str);
$str = preg_replace("/&#10;/i","",$str);
var_dump($str);
?>
```

The output of this code is:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'
&#10;
&#10;&amp;lt;TABLE'</font> <i>(length=13)</i>
</pre>
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'
&#10;
&#10;&amp;lt;TABLE'</font> <i>(length=13)</i>
</pre>
```

And the extracted value is an empty array... After further investigation i discovered through a `var_dump()` of my source string that there is a 
 at the end of each line.
I have no clue of what this html char code is and how to remove it.

Comment: Take out the double quotes and replace them with single quotes in preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first thing is I'm assuming that you have run imap_mime_header_decode already and you have the result.

Assuming you're working in the UTF8 charset and not ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 charsets you can try

```
utf8_encode($string);
```

EDIT
Whoops... to remove or replace the char you can use

```
preg_replace('/&#10/','<alt>',$string);
```

Just place your alternative character in where  is. You can replace it with nothing by doing

```
preg_replace('/&#10/','',$string);
```

You can also run an array through preg_replace like

```
$string = $myFile;
$search = array('/&#10/','/sec/');
$replace = array('','<alt>');
preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

[This may also be relevant to you.](http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=6129)

Comment: I'm using:
      $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1);
      $message = imap_qprint($message);
To get the content, it's already decoded.

Comment: If it is already in UTF8/your preferred charset then you should be able to go ahead with preg_replace for the messed up character, can you tell me what charset the header of the email is declaring in the email? Also are you inserting this into a database? If so, what encoding is the database using?

Comment: I tried what you suggested in your edit but the replacement isn't working. (I'm not fetching the data from database). The charset of the email is UTF-8.

Comment: @Artusamak did you try both formats? With the variables and array()? Could you please post your code with preg_replace along with the input and output vars?